# Active X control

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

Is it possible to Allow **Active X** to run automatically through code?
I want the Active X toolbar not to show and the **Active x** to run as soon as I run my application. Any idea?

Comment: I've answered your question as asked, but it would help if you explain what problem you are attempting to solve, as there may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would be a massive security hole if that was allowed, as it would allow a web-page to execute arbitrary code with the full privileges of the user.

What you can do is configure Internet Explorer to automatically execute ActiveX controls for a given security zone. This would be suitable for, e.g., an intranet environment where you have full control over the clients.

This can be automatically performed using Active Directory Group Policy, or manually at each client by launching IE and clicking Tools → Options → Security, and configuring the security policy for the relevant zone.

**BEWARE**: You should not set the Internet zone to allow automatic downloading and execution of ActiveX controls. This would expose the client machine to a huge risk from malware.